# Webform CiviCRM Date Field corrupted on Receipt

Tags: webform-civicrm

CiviCRM 4.7.30, current Webform CiviCRM 7.x-4.19

When the user receives their receipt it prints the Date field in the table as this:

20180313115320

Which I assume is....

2018 / 03 / 13 / 11:53:20

How do we resolve this?

The receipts on line template is:

```
   {if $receive_date}
  <tr>
   <td {$labelStyle}>
    {ts}Date{/ts}
   </td>
   <td {$valueStyle}>
    {$receive_date} 
   </td>
  </tr>
 {/if}
```

Also, strangely enough, no transaction ID is present

Paypal WPP is the payment processor.

Comment: What does that receive_date look like in the database? Look in the civicrm_contribution table;

Comment: Receive date is: 2018-03-13 11:53:20

Comment: So which receipt are you sending? Online Contribution or Event or message template via CiviRules/Email API or webform email?

Comment: The receipt text is coming from the civicontribute page and it's using the civicrm template for the receipt. We are not using Civirules/email API or webform email (but could if those work better?)

Comment: For what it's worth it seems like resetting the template to default and re-applying custom formatting may have resolved this issue. That doesn't tell me exactly what went wrong yet, hope to come back and update. Perhaps the template was changed in the 4.6 to 4.7 update in a way that affected date formatting?

Comment: Phew - glad you solved it; I've not seen this yet on any of ours; I do think smarty templates aren't all that smart - sometimes... I spent some time myself just now trying to explode a string and gave up!